# Bulk Insert in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

```
$list = [];

foreach($RoleDetails["Data"]["Permissions"] as $Permission) {
    $MyModel = new UserRolePermissionModel();
    $MyModel->UserID                  = $User->UserID;
    $MyModel->RolePermissionID        = $Permission->RolePermissionID;
    $MyModel->IsActive                = $Permission->IsActive;

    array_push($list, $MyModel);
}
\DB::table('tbluserrolepermission')->insert($list);
```

**Below are the error details**

```
QueryException {#293 ▼
  #sql: "insert into `tbluserrolepermission` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  #bindings: array:18 [▶]
  #message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `tbluserrolepermission` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`) values ({"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":19,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":20,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":21,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":22,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":23,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":24,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":25,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":26,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":27,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":28,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":29,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":30,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":31,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":32,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":33,"IsActive":0,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":34,"IsActive":1,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":35,"IsActive":1,"IsProtectionAvailable":0,"IsProtectionReadOnly":1}, {"UserID":21,"RolePermissionID":36,"IsActive":1,"IsProtectionAvailable":1,"IsProtectionReadOnly":0}))"
  #code: "42S22"
  #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\AS4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
  #line: 761
  -previous: PDOException {#356 ▶}
  +errorInfo: array:3 [▶]
  +"previous": PDOException {#356 ▶}
  -trace: {▶}
}
```

Comment: what is there inside  {#285 ▶}  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it like below.

```
foreach($RoleDetails["Data"]["RolePermissions"] as $RolePermission) {
    $data = [
        'UserID'                => $User->UserID,
        'RolePermissionID'      => $RolePermission->RolePermissionID,
        'IsActive'              => $RolePermission->IsActive,
        'IsProtectionAvailable' => $RolePermission->IsProtectionAvailable,
        'IsProtectionReadOnly'  => $RolePermission->IsProtectionReadOnly
    ];
    array_push($list,$data);
}
\DB::table('tbluserrolepermission')->insert($list);
```

or it could be like this.

```
UserRolePermissionModel::insert($list);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not working, because you are not providing an array of arrays with only the values matching the column names to populate the database with.

**Example**

Lets say you want to populate an array of users and save them to the database. The following example would do that.

```
DB::table('users')->insert([  
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

Note that `email` and `votes` in the above example are 2 columns in the `users` table. Note also that only an array of other arrays are passed to the insert method. What you are trying to insert is actually an array of eloquent model objects.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
UserRolePermissionModel::insert($list->toArray());

OR 

DB::table('table')->insert($list->toArray());
```